# Confusing question on integers and probability

Tags: probability

A number $\,d\,$ is chosen at random from the first $10$ positive integers.

What is the probability for the following events?

- $d\,$ is an even number.
- $d\;$ is an odd number.
- $d\;$ is a prime number.
- $3 \vert d$

Comment: First tell us what _you_ think.

Comment: What did you try? Can you exhibit the set of the even numbers among $\{1,...,10\}$, the set of odd numbers, and the set of prime numbers less than or equal 10 ?

Comment: There are $10$ choices. We assume that by "at random" the author means that these $10$ numbers are **equally likely** to be chosen. How many of these possible choices are even? How many are prime? How many are divisible by $3$?

Answer (score 2):

For example for (1): how many even integers are there? Well, now divide this numbers by the *total* ammount of integers there. (By "there" I mean in the set of the first 10 positive integers).

**All** the others are done in a similar way.

Answer (score 0):

With these simple probabilities, all you need to do is create a fraction with the total possibilities on the bottom, and then how many possibilites there are of what you want on the top.

For Example:

a) There are 5 even numbers between 1 and 10 - (2,4,6,8,10) - Because there are 5 even numbers and 10 numbers total, take 5/10 and simplify to get 1/2.